# Android GPS is returning outdated info

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

In my current application, the location data that is returned is outdated.  I use a method that gets updates based on min time/distance between updates.  However, lets say i turn my phone off, drive to another city, and then turn the phone back on.  In this case my GPS reading will be off.  How do i force the app to get the current location NOT getLastKnownLocation().

I have heard of a locationListener but everything i have read is very vague on how to use it.

Here is the code I have just in case this clarifies whats going on:

```
public class GPSHandling extends Service implements LocationListener{

    private final Context myContext;

    //flag for gps status
    public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    //flag for network status
    public boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // used to determine if i can get a location either by network or GPS
    public boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location myloc;

    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    public int MIN_TIME_BTWN_UPDATE = 500*10;  // in miliseconds, so 10sec 
    public int MIN_DISTANCE_BTWN_UPDATE = 10;  // in meters 
    protected LocationManager locManager;

    public GPSHandling(Context context){
        this.myContext= context;
        getLocation();
    }
    public Location getLocation(){
        try{
            locManager =(LocationManager) myContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // now get gps status
            isGPSEnabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //now the same for network
            isNetworkEnabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){
                // do nothing since neither provider are enabled (this.cangetlocation = false but its already set to that by default)
            }
            else{
                this.canGetLocation=true;
                //first get values for locManager from the network provider. send parameters telling when to update
                if(isNetworkEnabled){
                    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BTWN_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_BTWN_UPDATE, this);
                    Log.d("provider", "network");
                    //if we are successful, then check to see if the location manager isnt null. attempt to get the current location from the manager
                    if (locManager != null){
                        myloc =locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            // after getting the current location, attempt to get the latitude and longitude values
                            if (myloc != null){
                                latitude = myloc.getLatitude();
                                longitude = myloc.getLongitude();
                                              }
                                           }
                                    }
                //now get values for locManager from the GPS provider. send parameters telling when to update
                if(isGPSEnabled){
                    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BTWN_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_BTWN_UPDATE, this);
                    Log.d("provider", "GPS");
                }
                //if we are successful, then check to see if the location manager isnt null. attempt to get the current location from the manager
                    if(locManager!= null){
                        myloc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    // after getting the current location, attempt to get the latitude and longitude values
                        if(myloc != null){
                            latitude = myloc.getLatitude();
                            longitude = myloc.getLongitude();
                        }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myloc;
    }
    // get an update of the current latitude by using this class method
    public double getMyLatitude(){
        if (myloc!= null){
            latitude = myloc.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }
    //get an update of the current longitude by using this class method
    public double getMyLongitude(){
        if (myloc != null ){
            longitude = myloc.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    // use this method to find if app can get the current location
    public boolean canGetMyLocation(){
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showGPSDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
        // Setting Dialog Title 
        alert.setTitle("Location Setting");
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alert.setMessage("GPS is not enabled, do you want to enable this now in the settins menue?");

        // setting icon to dialog
        //alert.setIcon(R.drawable.)

        // on pressing settings button
        alert.setPositiveButton("Settins", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                myContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //on pressing cancel button
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // showing the alert dialog
        alert.show();
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locManager !=null){
            locManager.removeUpdates(GPSHandling.this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already half using `LocationListener` in your code. You just didn't fully implement the code.

This method bellow is empty in your code:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This is the method that is called everytime GPS produces an location update.

You should complete it doing something like:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, Will this take care of the fact that an old location could be cashed?

Comment: In `onLocationChange()` you only receive new (on the spot) locations. If you use `getLastKnownLocation()` you allways receive a cached location (can be very old or can have been cached just a second  before).

Comment: is android constantly getting GPS locations updates (im wondering how android knows the location has changed and call this method)?  If so why do i have to tell tell it the intervals of when to update locations?

Comment: It depends on what you request. You choose how frequently you want it to acquire a new location (ex. every 2 minutes) and how farway from the previous location the new one should be, to be reported. You can read full details in `LocationManager` documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: I didnt word my question well.  How does android know that my minimum distance was hit if it needs to make a call out even know that.  Is it constantly checking to see if it has moved at all? wouldnt this take alot of battery?

Comment: GPS only checks position with the frequency you set (if you set it to 0 is continous, if you set it to 2000 is every 2 secounds). Then when it runs the check at the time set above, he compares the new position with the previous one to see if menimum distance was met. If distance was met, you get a new location, if not the location is discard and you get nothing. So, if you set time for 5 minutes and you move immediatly the minimum distance, you will get the update only after the 5 minutes interval.

Comment: Regarding battery, more frequent updates result in more battery consuption, because it requires the GPS to calculate the location. Minimum distance dosen't affect battery, as gps as already done the work to calculate the position.

Comment: Just for reference, my device (is a medium range one) runs for about 6 hours with gps on continous acquisition mode (time equal to 0). But it should be different from device to device.

Comment: i see. so having a continuous frequency is going to kill the battery regardless on weather i chose to actually update the location shown on my device (amusing displaying the graphical update and finishing the calculations is negligible). Now im wondering why the hell anyone would chose NOT to update the values based solely on min distance/time if you already received the new data (might as well use that data assuming its all coming from GPS)...

Comment: Now that I have a second thought about it, beside location gps also calculates altitude, which is even more complex and requires at least one additional satelitte data. May be when it find that location is closer then minimum, it can avoid some work and save same battery... I've never read into the details on internal gps calculations, so this may not be correct.

Comment: ok that explains it. I was just confused because it didnt make sense to decide on using GPS only when i had moved a certain distance but knowing that distance requires GPS itself (catch22).  Since it might get to forego calculating altitude that would explain how it saves on battery. Where is Rero Meier when you need him?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the corresponding docs?
Look at [Location API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) for the start.

`LocationListener` is actually pretty straight-forward to use and the only (clean) way to reliably retrieve the device's location.

Answer (score 0):

Location data usually take up to **30 seconds to fully warm up**. As you asked for the `getLastKnownLocation()` you, indeed, could have a outdated location returned.

Read more about it at [Location strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) by Google itself.